# Spring Conditional Annotation Operator

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need to put a condition on two configuration classes for spring security. When the condition is true, use configuration A, and when the condition is false, use configuration B.

I currently use two condition classes. They produce opposite results.

Is it possible for me to use some operator in the conditional annotation? Something like this?

```
@Conditional( value = !MyCondition.class )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Conditional` annotation receives a class name that implements the `Condition` interface and creates the bean if that condition is matched.

If the condition you're trying to implement is simply the negation of another existing condition then you can extend from the existing condition and override the `matches`method as the negation of invoking the parent class `matches` method.

Answer (score 2):

The code to get *inverse* condition in Spring.

```
   public class MyCondition extends SpringBootCondition {
        public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, 
             AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
          ConditionMessage.Builder message = ConditionMessage.forCondition("MyCondition");

          boolean enable = Binder.get(context.getEnvironment()).bind("execute.enable", 
                Boolean.class).orElse(false);
          if (enable) {
              return ConditionOutcome.match(message.foundExactly("execute enabled"));
          }

          return ConditionOutcome.noMatch(message.notAvailable("execute disable"));
       }
    }

    public class InversedCondition extends MyCondition {

          @Override
          public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(
              ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
            return ConditionOutcome.inverse(super.getMatchOutcome(context, metadata));
          }
    }
```

Sometimes, you don't really need an InversedCondition. If you use MyCondition for EnableRun class. Then you can use **@ConditionalOnMissingBean(EnableHello.class)** for the DisalbeRun class.

Comment: ConditionalOnMissingBean was what I needed - nice and simple

Answer (score 0):

We can extend the `NoneNestedConditions` (since spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.3.0) and placing the predefined `Condition` inside the definition as a nested class condition as in the example below:

```
public class NotMyCondition extends NoneNestedConditions {

    public NotMyCondition() {
        super(ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN);
    }

    @Conditional(MyCondition.class)
    public static class NotOnMyCondition {}
}
```

If this is the only defined condition on this nested condition, it will actually negate the original one.

Note: I have found that if `MyCondition` extends the `Any/AllNestedConditions` class then the extention solution with overriding the super's method would not work and can lead to unexpected behavior.